# Non-persistant user sessions with hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, live-cd, persistence

Live CD/USB users often ask how they can have persistent changes but I'm after the reverse - I am building a minimal thin client using a hard disk and want it to act live a live CD, where all changes are lost. I also need admins to be able to make persistent changes. Can I achieve this?

All I have is minimal install, X-windows, Firefox and Citrix Receiver. It won't help to point out that there isn't much for a user to change, nor to suggest using an actual live CD, this has to be a hard-disk install. I'm thinking that redirecting all changes to a RAM disk would be ideal but I have no idea how to do this and would welcome some expert advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can run your distro as live from hard disk itself. You can create manual entry in grub2 as per the instruction in given link [run-linux-live-images-from-hard-disk-in-linux](http://www.tecmint.com/run-linux-live-images-from-hard-disk-in-linux/). But still i am searching for a way to make it persistent. I hope that helps.